# Why the Favicon isn't showing on frontend on my Wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress

I am facing an issue with my WordPress site which doesn't show favicon on frontend while it's shown on the backend.

I am using Lightspeed cache plugin as optimizer.

Any solution ? without installing another plugin for favicon.

Comment: Clear Website cache before checking this on the front end as you are using the cache plugin on the website.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="icon" href="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/cropped-smiling-sun-1.png" sizes="32x32" /> <link rel="icon" href="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/cropped-smiling-sun-1.png" sizes="192x192" /> <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/cropped-smiling-sun-1.png" />
```

From another similar question that's answer seems to have worked. Going to try it myself soon. I'll edit then.